# Celery 3.1.19 creating too many threads for each worker causing the server to overload with 100% CPU unable to create more threads

Tags: rabbitmq, celery

Use Case : Using celery in Django framework (version 1.6 ) to schedule tasks that essentially write to the database . I have only one custom queue that the celery beat scheduler puts tasks on . Created one celery worker that listens on this queue that has a concurrency of 8

Issue : Each of the 8 individual worker proceeds to create threads that are never reclaimed (my guess) . This results in too many threads ( i have seen count go up to 20k threads ) . Within a period of 4-5 hours , the thread count touches 10k !

Error I See : can’t start new thread .

Python traceback on who is starting new threads gave me this : Calling the django save creates a new thread . “adgroup” here is an django model object

```
[2015-12-03 18:40:17,133: WARNING/Worker-3] adgroup.save(update_fields=['bids_today', 'impressions_today', 'spent_today', 'last_metric_update_time'])
[2015-12-03 18:40:17,887: WARNING/Worker-3] File "/home/ec2-user/venv/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 545, in save
[2015-12-03 18:40:17,887: WARNING/Worker-3] force_update=force_update, update_fields=update_fields)
[2015-12-03 18:40:18,715: WARNING/Worker-3] File "/home/ec2-user/venv/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 582, in save_base
[2015-12-03 18:40:18,716: WARNING/Worker-3] update_fields=update_fields, raw=raw, using=using)
[2015-12-03 18:40:18,716: WARNING/Worker-3] File "/home/ec2-user/venv/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/dispatch/dispatcher.py", line 185, in send
[2015-12-03 18:40:18,716: WARNING/Worker-3] response = receiver(signal=self, sender=sender, **named)
[2015-12-03 18:40:19,300: INFO/MainProcess] Task ExtendTV.celery_tasks.stats_collector.collectAdGroupMetricsTask[2ae52b3d-77b9-46d3-93ac-d7fad9b96382] succeeded in 26.486441362s: None
[2015-12-03 18:40:19,395: WARNING/Worker-3] File "/home/ec2-user/venv/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/haystack/signals.py", line 48, in handle_save
[2015-12-03 18:40:19,593: WARNING/Worker-3] index.update_object(instance, using=using)
[2015-12-03 18:40:19,593: WARNING/Worker-3] File "/home/ec2-user/venv/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/haystack/indexes.py", line 274, in update_object
[2015-12-03 18:40:19,593: WARNING/Worker-3] backend.update(self, [instance])
[2015-12-03 18:40:19,593: WARNING/Worker-3] File "/home/ec2-user/venv/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/haystack/backends/whoosh_backend.py", line 208, in update
[2015-12-03 18:40:20,515: WARNING/Worker-3] writer.commit()
[2015-12-03 18:40:20,516: WARNING/Worker-3] File "/home/ec2-user/venv/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/whoosh/writing.py", line 1043, in commit
[2015-12-03 18:40:21,318: WARNING/Worker-3] self.start()
[2015-12-03 18:40:21,642: WARNING/Worker-3] File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/threading.py", line 748, in start
[2015-12-03 18:40:22,340: WARNING/Worker-3] _start_new_thread(self.__bootstrap, ())
[2015-12-03 18:40:22,340: WARNING/Worker-3] error: can't start new thread
```

Misc Info : 
AS you can see from the picture the memory is well within the normal range . 
This “thread issue” is not present in the previous version of celery 3.0.x . However here the memory becomes pretty high

Celery command I use to create a worker :

```
celery -A ProjectName worker -l DEBUG -Q ExampleQueueName
```

Celery setting that I use :

```
CELERY_DEFAULT_QUEUE = 'default'
CELERY_DEFAULT_EXCHANGE_TYPE = 'direct'
CELERY_DEFAULT_ROUTING_KEY = 'default'
CELERY_RESULT_SERIALIZER = 'json'
CELERY_ACCEPT_CONTENT = ['json']
CELERY_TASK_SERIALIZER = 'json'
CELERY_RESULT_SERIALIZER = 'json'
CELERY_TASK_RESULT_EXPIRES=60*60*24
CELERYD_PREFETCH_MULTIPLIER = 128
```

Other related settings :
Using rabbitmq 3.5.4 as the message broker

UPDATE :

```
def collectAdGroupMetricsTask(*args, **kwargs):
    try:
        adgroup = AdGroup.objects.get(id=kwargs.get("adgroupID"))
        collectAdGroupMetrics(adgroup)
    except Exception as e:
        logger.error("Could not retreive AdGroup for collectAdGroupMetrics. " + str(e))
    return

def collectAdGroupMetrics(adgroup, currDate=None):
    Value1=function1_making_another_db_call()
    Value2=function2_making_another_db_call()
    adgroup.fieldname1 = Value1
    adgroup.fieldname2 = Value2    
    adgroup.save(update_fields=['fieldname1', 'fieldname2'])
```

[Example of worker process having lots of threads.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CJTBz.jpg)

Comment: Can you post details about adgroup.save and ExtendTV.celery_tasks.stats_collector.collectAdGroupMetricsTask?

Comment: adgroup.save() is a regular django save function . 
Celrey beat places the celery task periodicMetricsCollectorTask every 15 minutes on the queue . This periodicMetricsCollectorTask calls collectAdGroupMetricsTask with a django model object .

Comment: Is it even acceptable to use celery to save to the database ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There was an issue with whoosh (python package) which was trying to acquire a write lock and kept waiting leading to the creation of so many threads.Hence removed whoosh from the list of installed apps in django.
Also using maxtasksperchild config in celery to prevent memory from growing continuously.

Answer (score 0):

- First of all installed package **gevent** inside pythonic virtual environment.
- Next made some changes to command for running **celery**
- In the end, i appended parameter `--pool gevent`. By default, **celery** uses pool 'prefork', which is supposed to have some bugs.
- After choosing **gevent** number of processes of **celery** lowered to the number of children (concurrency) processes.